# SQL Count where difference > number

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  VEHICLES
  JOIN INSPECTIONS ON VEHICLES.RECORD_NUMBER = INSPECTIONS.VEHICLE_RECORD_NUMBER_FW
WHERE
 INSPECTIONS.ODOMETER - INSPECTIONS.OLD_ODOMETER > 3000
```

I get the error

> The multi-part identifier "INSPECTIONS.ODOMETER" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "INSPECTIONS.OLD_ODOMETER" could not be
>   bound.

What I would like to get is vehicles where this odometer difference in inspections table is higher than 3000.

Comment: Are `ODOMETER` and `OLD_ODOMETER` columns on the `INSPECTIONS` table?

Comment: @PaulWilliams Yes, I want to count Vehicles from ```VEHICLES``` and ```ODOMETER``` and ```OLD_ODOMETER``` are in ```INSPECTIONS``` TABLE which I would use only for this condition

Comment: Show us the table definition for INSPECTIONS.

Comment: @Quaves, something is not right here.  Either those columns are not on the INSPECTIONS table, or the table has a different name, or it is in a different database / schema.

Comment: @jarlh Unfortunately I have no access to database, I can only write queries in frontend and read error messages I get...

Comment: Try `select top 1 * from INSPECTIONS`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what value the `JOIN` is bringing in.  If you use column aliases, does that fix the problem?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INSPECTIONS i 
WHERE i.ODOMETER - i.OLD_ODOMETER > 3000
```

I would be surprised if you have vehicle identifiers on inspections that are not in `VEHICLES`, which is why the `JOIN` seems unnecessary.

Comment: What about inspections of vehicles that are not in the database anymore (sold or scrapped) ?

Comment: I need to count all vehicles from ```VEHICLES``` and condition should be made using ```INSPECTIONS``` table as ```ODOMETER``` and ```OLD_ODOMETER``` are only in this table.

Comment: @Quaves . . . Why would you have inspections on vehicles that are no in the `vehicles` table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Inspections are made every day for every vehicle and there needs to be history of all vehicle inspections

Comment: @Quaves . . . You only need to `JOIN` to `VEHICLES` for your query if that table is filtering the results.  Otherwise, all the information you need is in `INSPECTIONS`.